# Including libraries from Microsoft.Extensions namespace causes exceptions in other Nuget packages

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, .net-standard-2.0

I've run into a really weird issue with Nuget packages in .net standard.

I've got 2 projects - a .net standard 2.0 library and a .net core 2.1 console application. If I include anything from the Microsoft.Extensions namespace in the .net standard library it causes exceptions in other Nuget packages in the .net core application. I've tried `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`

The exception is:

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.MemoryExtensions' from assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
```

I'm not quite sure the reason why, but it's definitely reproducible.

Comment: Hey Michael. Do you have a repro solution I can take a look at?

Comment: Did you ever get this issue  fixed Michael? I'm having the same problem now.